# How to share photos directly from Dropbox instead of links?

Tags: dropbox

Using Dropbox on Android, selecting photos only allows me to share a link to them instead of sharing the photos physically. When I share photos from Dropbox to other apps like Google+ or Facebook, I expect those photos to be physically copied/uploaded to that service so that the images embed in the posts properly. However only the links are shared.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox application on PCs copies files, but on Android it copies links, because of limited memory.

In any case I would expect that links would always be shared, but that certain sites such as G+ and FB import seamlessly.

So, if you're using an app which doesn't do this, you'll have to do it yourself the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is not. Dropbox used to let you hotlink (link to the file directly), but that was changed a few years back. There were people who were running web sites off of Dropbox and serving large files. To stop that behavior, the ability to hotlink to Dropbox files have been revoked. You have to go to Dropbox.com and download the file manually. If you have a lot of files, you can zip it together and give one file to download.

Comment: He does want to download the file, he just wants it to happen through the app instead of the website and then directly share that *local copy* with Facebook and such.  I don't think this addresses the question.

Comment: Once you go to the Dropbox link, tap and hold on the image. This should give you option to save to camera roll. Go to Facebook app and select image from camera roll.